# Notation for using a relation as a function from an element to set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, relations

Let $R \subseteq X \times Y$

Is there a commonly used term/notation for the functions $f:X\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$ and $g:Y\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ defined as follows?:

$$f(x) = \{ y \mid (x, y) \in R\}$$
$$g(y) = \{ x \mid (x, y) \in R\}$$

Since these values are a very elementary part of the structure of a relation, I'd think that this shows up commonly and might have a name.

If there is notation for $f$ then perhaps $g$ doesn't need different notation as $g$ is just $f$ on $R^{-1}$

Comment: The question is fine as it is but I think some more context about what prompted this question might help stir up some ideas

Comment: I'm just using set theory to formalize something very niche (as it should be used) and I need to refer to these functions quite often so I defined my own terminology. Though I'd love to know if there was some standard terminology and use it.

Comment: In analogy to functions, I've seen $R(A) = \{y\in Y\mid (a,y)\in R\text{ for some }a\in A\}$ and $R^{-1}(B) = \{x\in X\mid (x,b)\in R\text{ for some }b\in B\}$. By abuse of notation, $R(\{x\})$ is often written $R(x)$, and context is meant to provide disambiguation where needed. I'm not sure about your universal quantification, given that you are putting it outside the set and out-of-place for logical notation. I'm guessing you mean that for each $x\in X$ you define $f(x)$ to be `blah`, etc.  In any case, as this is not universal, I would suggest defining the notation briefly before using.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, that's what it was supposed to mean. I'll clarify. I like the notation. If you could put it up as an answer with some more information about where you've seen it being used, it would be a good answer.

Comment: I don't know about specific notation, but $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are often called, respectively, the $x$-*vertical section of* $R$ and the $y$-*horizontal section of* $R.$ See [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vertical+section%22+%22descriptive+set+theory%22) and [this other google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vertical+section%22+%22descriptive+set+theory%22&tbm=bks).

Comment: In the case where the $R$ is the membership relation in a model of a set theory, $f$ is sometimes called the *de Giorgi map* of $f$. Or you could call $f$ the "power transpose" of $R$, after the relation/power object adjunction in topos theory.